# How to distinguish different exceptions/classes with the same structure in typescript

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I know that Typescript has [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). But for my use case i need distinguish between different types of exceptions with the same structure. Is there easy way how to accomplish it? I am thinking about adding some unique field into each of them, but i would prefer solution which require changes only in parent error.

```
class FooError extends Error {};
class BarError extends Error {};

function doSomething(): void | FooError {
    return new BarError();    
}
```

Comment: If you don't change the structure of each child class, you can't tell them apart.  So you'll have to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/1WG8Mw) if you want this to work.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, your child classes need to be structurally distinct from each other.  You can't do this by modifying *only* the parent class.

In order to distinguish the child classes from each other, you could add a `private` or `protected` field to each subclass.  Private fields are treated nominally, not structurally, so they can even have the same structure if you want:

```
class FooError extends Error {
    private __prop?: any; // needs to be in each subclass, despite looking the same
};
class BarError extends Error {
    private __prop?: any; // needs to be in each subclass, despite looking the same
};

function doSomething(): void | FooError {
    return new BarError();    // error
}
```

but I'd suggest instead adding a discriminating field like this:

```
class FooError extends Error {
    readonly type = "FooError";
};
class BarError extends Error {
    readonly type = "BarError";
};

function doSomething(): void | FooError {
    return new BarError();    // error
}
```

since you could use it to distinguish a `FooError` from a `BarError` both at compile time and at runtime:

```
function distinguishError(err: FooError | BarError) {
    if (err.type === "BarError") {
        err // BarError
    } else {
        err // FooError
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABABQE4EsBuYAuUAYllADYAmKA3sCvSomWDDCkQPYcCiGGHGFFAAehEBTa9+g2gzko42PIRQB9VYo5wA-AC4UYEAE8A3HQYBfM3KYs2AITAYpAoaKjjJfV7Pn1FuASo6po6+oam5vRWwFEoAGYAriCI+FgcICgUHADKHND4ABZYIADmABQAlPo4HFhUAD7sXC4ycXIYUPiJGJkgUADuKI7O3hhVJnIA9FNCY3EWwIugkLAIyCgAIlgwiNgQJORUvvS2rM08Y25iEiitNO0MnWDZIGRGKPhGcKgAvCgAIk4l2kAOslnBp2Y5xG9xENy80gefnoz1e70+3z+gNhYzBCzMcSSKTSGSyuXyXWKZSqNTqjQu9xO8k63V6KH6Q1x0gm01mUHmcmWcmJqXSmQoOzSZUSO0KrXKAow+mB9ya3IElWRKKw8RQir4ADovj8UL9zTinK0AVrmSi5oIZsMrYKURYhGQYKg7SilSgnarXX5FkKlrEgA)